# Laravel socialite Save avatar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

everybody, I need to Save image name in the avatar column in the database 
and save the image in public/Storage/users My Code Here Save image link in the database any help, please.

```
public function handleProviderCallback($service)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($service)->user();
    $FindUser = User::where('email',$user->getEmail())->first();
        if($FindUser){
            Auth::login($FindUser);
        }
        else{
            $NewUser = new User;
            $NewUser->email = $user->getEmail();
            $NewUser->name  = $user->getName();
            $NewUser->avatar  = $user->getAvatar();
            $NewUser->password  = bcrypt(123456);
            $NewUser->save();
            Auth::login($NewUser);
        }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply fetch the data using `file_get_contents` function and process the retrieved data.

```
use File;
```

create a helper method to get the avatar

```
function getSocialAvatar($file, $path){
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
    return File::put(public_path() . $path . $user->getId() . ".jpg", $fileContents);
}
```

replace `$user->getAvatar()`

with the helper method

`getSocialAvatar($user->getAvatar(), 'path')`

Comment: thanks it worked fine but i need to save it in /public/storage/users

Comment: i have tried                     return File::put(public_path($path = '/public/storage/users') . $path . 'imaged' . ".jpg", $fileContents);