# Laravel 8 Jetstream Profile Photos with Socialite Avatars

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-socialite, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying Laravel 8 Jetstream with Laravel Socialite.
The problem is when I retrieve the avatar and use its URL to profile_photo_path. The blade file appends http://localhost:8000/storage/ that is causing the avatar not to display.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puS34.png)

I have enabled jetstream's profile photos on
**config/jetstream.php**

```
'features' => [
    Features::profilePhotos(),
    Features::accountDeletion(),
],
```

Here's how I store the user **app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php**

```php
    protected function registerOrLoginUser($user, $driver=null)
    {
        if(!is_null($driver)){
            $whereColumn = null;
            if($driver == 'facebook'){
                $whereColumn = "facebook_id";
            }
            if($driver == 'google'){
                $whereColumn = "google_id";
            }

            try{
                $findUser = User::where($whereColumn, $user->id)->first();
                if($findUser){
                    Auth::login($findUser);
                } else{
                    $newUser = new User();
                    $newUser->name = $user->name;
                    $newUser->email = $user->email;
                    $newUser->password = encrypt('');
                    $newUser->$whereColumn = $user->id;
                    $newUser->profile_photo_path = $user->getAvatar();
                    $newUser->save();
                    Auth::login($newUser);
                }
```

I saw the problem here **resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php**

```php
<button class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
   <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover" src="{{ Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" />
</button>
```

So I tried to remedy this blade file and put an if statement here :

```php
<button class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
    <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover" src="{{ (Auth::user()->google_id !== null ||  Auth::user()->facebook_id !== null ) ? Auth::user()->profile_photo_path : Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" />
</button>
```

The 'If statement' is flawed, it would break when socialite logged-in users decided to change their picture. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902674) but it only stores numeric value to my profile_photo_path.  Any idea how to make socialite and Jetstream's built-in profile photos work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied `getProfilePhotoUrlAtrribute` method from `vendor/laravel/jetstream/src/HasProfilePhoto.php`
to `App\Models\User` and modified it to accept avatar url from social site or retrieve uploaded photo.

```
<?php
    public function getProfilePhotoUrlAttribute()
    {

        $path = $this->profile_photo_path;

        if (Storage::disk($this->profilePhotoDisk())->exists($path)){
            return Storage::disk($this->profilePhotoDisk())->url($this->profile_photo_path);
        } 
        elseif (!empty($path)){
            // Use Photo URL from Social sites link... 
            return $path;
        }
        else {
            //empty path. Use defaultProfilePhotoUrl
            return $this->defaultProfilePhotoUrl();
        }
    }
?>
```

[Jetsream docs reference](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html#managing-profile-photos)

Answer (score 0):

@user2645113's answer adapted for 2023, laravel 10. The source and destination files are the same, but now the function name is `profilePhotoUrl`.

Im sure this code could be refactored better, but here is a working version:

```
/**
     * Get the URL to the user's profile photo.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
     */
    public function profilePhotoUrl(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::get(function () {

            $path = $this->profile_photo_path;

            if ($path != null && Storage::disk($this->profilePhotoDisk())->exists($path)) {
                return Storage::disk($this->profilePhotoDisk())->url($this->profile_photo_path);
            } elseif ($path != null && !empty($path)) {
                // Use Photo URL from Social sites link... 
                return $path;
            } else {
                //empty path. Use defaultProfilePhotoUrl
                return $this->defaultProfilePhotoUrl();
            }
        });
    }
```

Obviously, be sure to include:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```